# wso2 IS Active directory

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to connect Active Directory to WSO2 IS 5.0.0 . I have changed the primary store as Active Directory and Started the Identity Server, the below exception occurred.

Its working on IS 5.2.0 . But I want to test this with IS 5.0.0 .

```
[2016-11-11 12:00:25,266] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm} -  Cannot create org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:329)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:195)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:104)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:223)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:101)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:114)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:69)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.addAllRolesToUserRolesCache(ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java:2299)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.doCheckIsUserInRole(ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java:2182)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addInitialAdminData(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:3259)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.<init>(ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java:166)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.<init>(ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:102)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager.<init>(ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager.java:85)
    ... 27 more
[2016-11-11 12:00:25,268] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService} -  Cannot initialize the realm.
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:370)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:195)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:104)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:223)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:101)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:114)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:69)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:329)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.addAllRolesToUserRolesCache(ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java:2299)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.doCheckIsUserInRole(ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java:2182)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addInitialAdminData(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:3259)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.<init>(ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java:166)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.<init>(ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:102)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager.<init>(ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager.java:85)
    ... 27 more
[2016-11-11 12:00:25,268] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator} -  Cannot start User Manager Core bundle
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Cannot initialize the realm.
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:231)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:101)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:114)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:69)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:370)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:195)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:104)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:223)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:329)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.addAllRolesToUserRolesCache(ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java:2299)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.doCheckIsUserInRole(ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java:2182)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addInitialAdminData(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:3259)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.<init>(ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java:166)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.<init>(ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:102)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager.<init>(ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager.java:85)
    ... 27 more
Activating org.wso2.jaggery.scxml with RealmService enabled
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WSO2 Identity Server Primary Store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40546363/wso2-identity-server-primary-store)