# WSO2 Identity Server Primary Store

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I couldn't change Primary Store to Active Directory in WSO2 Identity Server. When change the user-mgt.xml and start the server below exception occurred. I use the WSO2 IS 5.0.0.

```
    [2016-11-11 16:13:48,048] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm} -  Cannot create org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:329)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:195)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:104)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:223)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:101)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:114)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:69)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.addAllRolesToUserRolesCache(ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java:2299)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.doCheckIsUserInRole(ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java:2182)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addInitialAdminData(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:3259)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.<init>(ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java:166)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.<init>(ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:102)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager.<init>(ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager.java:85)
    ... 27 more
```

This is the User-mgt.xml file I have updated.

```
<UserManager>
    <Realm>
        <Configuration>
        <AddAdmin>false</AddAdmin>
                <AdminRole>admin</AdminRole>
                <AdminUser>
                     <UserName>admin</UserName>
                     <Password>admin</Password>
                </AdminUser>
            <EveryOneRoleName>everyone</EveryOneRoleName> <!-- By default users in this role sees the registry root -->
            <Property name="dataSource">jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</Property>
        </Configuration>
    <!-- Following is the default user store manager. This user store manager is based on embedded-apacheds LDAP. It reads/writes users and roles into the           default apacheds LDAP user store. Descriptions about each of the following properties can be found in user management documentation of the      respective product. In case if user core cache domain is needed to identify uniquely set property <Property name="UserCoreCacheIdentifier">domain</Property>
         Note: Do not comment within UserStoreManager tags. Cause, specific tag names are used as tokens when building configurations for products. -->
    <!--UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager">
            <Property name="TenantManager">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.CommonHybridLDAPTenantManager</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionURL">ldap://localhost:${Ports.EmbeddedLDAP.LDAPServerPort}</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionName">uid=admin,ou=system</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionPassword">admin</Property>
            <Property name="Disabled">false</Property>           
            <Property name="passwordHashMethod">SHA</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameListFilter">(objectClass=person)</Property>
        <Property name="UserEntryObjectClass">wso2Person</Property>
            <Property name="UserSearchBase">ou=Users,dc=wso2,dc=org</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=person)(uid=?))</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameAttribute">uid</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="RolenameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="RolenameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property>
        <Property name="WriteGroups">true</Property>
        <Property name="EmptyRolesAllowed">true</Property>
            <Property name="GroupSearchBase">ou=Groups,dc=wso2,dc=org</Property>
            <Property name="GroupNameListFilter">(objectClass=groupOfNames)</Property>
            <Property name="GroupEntryObjectClass">groupOfNames</Property>
            <Property name="GroupNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=?))</Property>
            <Property name="GroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
            <Property name="SharedGroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
            <Property name="SharedGroupSearchBase">ou=SharedGroups,dc=wso2,dc=org</Property>
            <Property name="SharedGroupEntryObjectClass">groupOfNames</Property>
            <Property name="SharedGroupNameListFilter">(objectClass=groupOfNames)</Property>
            <Property name="SharedGroupNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=?))</Property>
            <Property name="SharedTenantNameListFilter">(objectClass=organizationalUnit)</Property>
            <Property name="SharedTenantNameAttribute">ou</Property>
            <Property name="SharedTenantObjectClass">organizationalUnit</Property>
        <Property name="MembershipAttribute">member</Property>
        <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
        <Property name="UserDNPattern">uid={0},ou=Users,dc=wso2,dc=org</Property>
            <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property>
            <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
            <Property name="SCIMEnabled">false</Property>
        </UserStoreManager-->

    <!-- Following is the configuration for internal JDBC user store. This user store manager is based on JDBC. In case if application needs to manage           passwords externally set property <Property name="PasswordsExternallyManaged">true</Property>. In case if user core cache domain is needed to          identify uniquely set property <Property name="UserCoreCacheIdentifier">domain</Property>. Furthermore properties, IsEmailUserName and                  DomainCalculation are readonly properties. 
         Note: Do not comment within UserStoreManager tags. Cause, specific tag names are used as tokens when building configurations for products. --> 
        <!--UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager">
            <Property name="TenantManager">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.JDBCTenantManager</Property>
        <Property name="ReadOnly">false</Property>
            <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
            <Property name="IsEmailUserName">false</Property>
            <Property name="DomainCalculation">default</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordDigest">SHA-256</Property>
            <Property name="StoreSaltedPassword">true</Property>
            <Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property>
        <Property name="WriteGroups">true</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameUniqueAcrossTenants">false</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordJavaRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">^[^~!#$;%^*+={}\\|\\\\&lt;&gt;,\'\"]{3,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="RolenameJavaRegEx">^[^~!#$;%^*+={}\\|\\\\&lt;&gt;,\'\"]{3,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="RolenameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
            <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property>
            <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
        <Property name="SharedGroupEnabled">false</Property>
            <Property name="SCIMEnabled">false</Property>
        </UserStoreManager-->

    <!-- If product is using an external LDAP as the user store in READ ONLY mode, use following user manager.
        In case if user core cache domain is needed to identify uniquely set property <Property name="UserCoreCacheIdentifier">domain</Property>
    -->
        <!--UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager">
            <Property name="TenantManager">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.CommonHybridLDAPTenantManager</Property>
            <Property name="ReadOnly">true</Property>
            <Property name="Disabled">false</Property>                       
        <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionURL">ldap://localhost:10389</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionName">uid=admin,ou=system</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionPassword">admin</Property>
        <Property name="passwordHashMethod">PLAIN_TEXT</Property>
            <Property name="UserSearchBase">ou=system</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameListFilter">(objectClass=person)</Property>
        <Property name="UserNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=person)(uid=?))</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameAttribute">uid</Property>
        <Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property>
            <Property name="GroupSearchBase">ou=system</Property>
            <Property name="GroupNameListFilter">(objectClass=groupOfNames)</Property>
        <Property name="GroupNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=?))</Property>
            <Property name="GroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
            <Property name="SharedGroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
            <Property name="SharedGroupSearchBase">ou=SharedGroups,dc=wso2,dc=org</Property>
            <Property name="SharedGroupNameListFilter">(objectClass=groupOfNames)</Property>
            <Property name="SharedTenantNameListFilter">(objectClass=organizationalUnit)</Property>
            <Property name="SharedTenantNameAttribute">ou</Property>
            <Property name="SharedTenantObjectClass">organizationalUnit</Property>
        <Property name="MembershipAttribute">member</Property>
            <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
        <Property name="ReplaceEscapeCharactersAtUserLogin">true</Property>
            <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property>
            <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
            <Property name="SCIMEnabled">false</Property>
        </UserStoreManager-->

    <!-- Active directory configuration is as follows.
        In case if user core cache domain is needed to identify uniquely set property <Property name="UserCoreCacheIdentifier">domain</Property>
        There are few special properties for "Active Directory". 
        They are : 
        1.Referral - (comment out this property if this feature is not reuired) This enables LDAP referral support.
        2.BackLinksEnabled - (Do not comment, set to true or false) In some cases LDAP works with BackLinksEnabled. In which role is stored
         at user level. Depending on this value we need to change the Search Base within code.
        3.isADLDSRole - (Do not comment) Set to true if connecting to an AD LDS instance else set to false.  
    -->
    <UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager">
            <Property name="TenantManager">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.CommonHybridLDAPTenantManager</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionURL">ldaps://192.168.52.31:636</Property> 
            <Property name="ConnectionName">CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=wso2,DC=test</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionPassword">xxxxxxx</Property>
            <Property name="UserSearchBase">CN=Users,DC=wso2,DC=test</Property>
            <Property name="UserEntryObjectClass">user</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameAttribute">cn</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=user)(cn=?))</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameListFilter">(objectClass=user)</Property>
            <Property name="DisplayNameAttribute"/>
            <Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property>
            <Property name="WriteGroups">true</Property>
            <Property name="GroupSearchBase">OU=Roles,DC=wso2,DC=test</Property>
            <Property name="GroupEntryObjectClass">group</Property>
            <Property name="GroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
            <Property name="GroupNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=group)(cn=?))</Property>
            <Property name="GroupNameListFilter">(objectcategory=group)</Property>
            <Property name="MembershipAttribute">member</Property>
            <Property name="MemberOfAttribute">memberOf</Property>
            <Property name="BackLinksEnabled">true</Property>
            <Property name="Referral">follow</Property>
            <Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="UsernameJavaRegExViolationErrorMsg">Username pattern policy violated</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordJavaRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordJavaRegExViolationErrorMsg">Password length should be within 5 to 30 characters</Property>
            <Property name="RolenameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="RolenameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="SCIMEnabled">false</Property>
            <Property name="IsBulkImportSupported">false</Property>
            <Property name="EmptyRolesAllowed">true</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordHashMethod">PLAIN_TEXT</Property>
            <Property name="MultiAttributeSeparator">,</Property>
            <Property name="isADLDSRole">false</Property>
            <Property name="userAccountControl">512</Property>
            <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>     
            <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property>                     
            <Property name="kdcEnabled">false</Property>
            <Property name="defaultRealmName">WSO2.TEST</Property>
            <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionPoolingEnabled">false</Property>
            <Property name="LDAPConnectionTimeout">5000</Property>
            <Property name="ReadTimeout"/>
            <Property name="RetryAttempts"/>
        </UserStoreManager>

    <!-- If product is using an external LDAP as the user store in read/write mode, use following user manager 
        In case if user core cache domain is needed to identify uniquely set property <Property name="UserCoreCacheIdentifier">domain</Property>
    -->
    <!--UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager">
            <Property name="TenantManager">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.CommonHybridLDAPTenantManager</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionURL">ldap://localhost:10389</Property>
            <Property name="Disabled">false</Property>                       
            <Property name="ConnectionName">uid=admin,ou=system</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionPassword">secret</Property>
            <Property name="passwordHashMethod">PLAIN_TEXT</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameListFilter">(objectClass=person)</Property>
        <Property name="UserEntryObjectClass">inetOrgPerson</Property>
            <Property name="UserSearchBase">ou=system</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=person)(uid=?))</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameAttribute">uid</Property>
        <Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="RolenameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="RolenameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property>
        <Property name="WriteGroups">true</Property>
        <Property name="EmptyRolesAllowed">false</Property>
            <Property name="GroupSearchBase">ou=system</Property>
            <Property name="GroupNameListFilter">(objectClass=groupOfNames)</Property>
            <Property name="GroupEntryObjectClass">groupOfNames</Property>
            <Property name="GroupNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=?))</Property>
            <Property name="GroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
            <Property name="SharedGroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
            <Property name="SharedGroupSearchBase">ou=SharedGroups,dc=wso2,dc=org</Property>
            <Property name="SharedGroupEntryObjectClass">groupOfNames</Property>
            <Property name="SharedGroupNameListFilter">(objectClass=groupOfNames)</Property>
            <Property name="SharedGroupNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=?))</Property>
            <Property name="SharedTenantNameListFilter">(objectClass=organizationalUnit)</Property>
            <Property name="SharedTenantNameAttribute">ou</Property>
            <Property name="SharedTenantObjectClass">organizationalUnit</Property>
            <Property name="MembershipAttribute">member</Property>
            <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
        <Property name="ReplaceEscapeCharactersAtUserLogin">true</Property>
            <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property>
            <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
            <Property name="SCIMEnabled">false</Property>
        </UserStoreManager-->

    <!-- Following user manager is used by Identity Server (IS) as its default user manager. 
         IS will do token replacement when building the product. Therefore do not change the syntax. 
         If "kdcEnabled" parameter is true, IS will allow service principle management. Thus "ServicePasswordJavaRegEx", "ServiceNameJavaRegEx"
         properties control the service name format and service password formats.
         In case if user core cache domain is needed to identify uniquely set property <Property name="UserCoreCacheIdentifier">domain</Property>
    -->
    <!--UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager">
            <Property name="TenantManager">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.CommonHybridLDAPTenantManager</Property>
            <Property name="defaultRealmName">WSO2.ORG</Property>
            <Property name="kdcEnabled">false</Property>
            <Property name="Disabled">false</Property>                                   
            <Property name="ConnectionURL">ldap://localhost:${Ports.EmbeddedLDAP.LDAPServerPort}</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionName">uid=admin,ou=system</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionPassword">admin</Property>
            <Property name="passwordHashMethod">SHA</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameListFilter">(objectClass=person)</Property>
            <Property name="UserEntryObjectClass">identityPerson</Property>
            <Property name="UserSearchBase">ou=Users,dc=wso2,dc=org</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=person)(uid=?))</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameAttribute">uid</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="ServicePasswordJavaRegEx">^[\\S]{5,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="ServiceNameJavaRegEx">^[\\S]{2,30}/[\\S]{2,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="RolenameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="RolenameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property>
        <Property name="WriteGroups">true</Property>
        <Property name="EmptyRolesAllowed">true</Property>
            <Property name="GroupSearchBase">ou=Groups,dc=wso2,dc=org</Property>
            <Property name="GroupNameListFilter">(objectClass=groupOfNames)</Property>
        <Property name="GroupEntryObjectClass">groupOfNames</Property>
            <Property name="GroupNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=?))</Property>
            <Property name="GroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
            <Property name="SharedGroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
            <Property name="SharedGroupSearchBase">ou=SharedGroups,dc=wso2,dc=org</Property>
            <Property name="SharedGroupEntryObjectClass">groupOfNames</Property>
            <Property name="SharedGroupNameListFilter">(objectClass=groupOfNames)</Property>
            <Property name="SharedGroupNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=?))</Property>
            <Property name="SharedTenantNameListFilter">(objectClass=organizationalUnit)</Property>
            <Property name="SharedTenantNameAttribute">ou</Property>
            <Property name="SharedTenantObjectClass">organizationalUnit</Property>
            <Property name="MembershipAttribute">member</Property>
            <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
        <Property name="UserDNPattern">uid={0},ou=Users,dc=wso2,dc=org</Property>
        <Property name="RoleDNPattern">cn={0},ou=Groups,dc=wso2,dc=org</Property>
        <Property name="SCIMEnabled">true</Property>
            <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property>
            <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
        </UserStoreManager-->

    <!--    Following configuration is for the CassandraUserStoreManager. The CassandraUserStoreManager is capable of using a Cassandra
        database as a user store. This user manager supports multiple credentials for authentication. Credential types can be defined
        and configured in the following configuration. The CassandraUserStoreManager does not ships with the any of the WSO2 Carbon
        Servers by default, therefor Cassandra user manager component needs to be installed to the Carbon Server befor using.

        And if this CassandraUserStoreManager is used as the primary user store with multi tenants, it should also implement a 
        compatible TenantManager and set property <Property name="TenantManager">FULL_QUALIFIED_TENANT_MANAGER_CLASS_NAME</Property>.
    -->
    <!--UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.cassandra.CassandraUserStoreManager">
        <Property name="Keyspace">User_KS3</Property>
        <Property name="Host">localhost</Property>
        <Property name="Port">9160</Property>
        <Property name="PasswordDigest">SHA-256</Property>
        <Property name="StoreSaltedPassword">true</Property>
        <Property name="AuthenticateWithAnyCredential">true</Property>
        <Property name="DomainName">multipleCredentialUserStoreDomain</Property>
            <MultipleCredentials>
            <Credential type="Default">org.wso2.carbon.user.cassandra.credentialtypes.EmailCredential</Credential>
            <Credential type="Email">org.wso2.carbon.user.cassandra.credentialtypes.EmailCredential</Credential>
            <Credential type="PhoneNumber">org.wso2.carbon.user.cassandra.credentialtypes.PhoneNumberCredential</Credential>
            <Credential type="Device">org.wso2.carbon.user.cassandra.credentialtypes.DeviceCredential</Credential>
            <Credential type="External">org.wso2.carbon.user.cassandra.credentialtypes.ExternalProviderCredential</Credential>
            </MultipleCredentials>
    </UserStoreManager-->

        <AuthorizationManager
            class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager">
            <Property name="AdminRoleManagementPermissions">/permission</Property>
        <Property name="AuthorizationCacheEnabled">true</Property>
        <Property name="GetAllRolesOfUserEnabled">true</Property>
        </AuthorizationManager>
    </Realm>
</UserManager>
```

Comment: what is the IS version you are trying? Can you add the user-mgt.xml here (make sure you mask any passwords and sensitive information)?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a [known issue](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/DOCUMENTATION-948).

To fix it, enable `GetAllRolesOfUserEnabled` property of `<AuthorizationManager>` section as mentioned in "When working with Active Directory" section of [this document](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Configuring+an+Active+Directory+User+Store).

Comment: Hi Bathiya, Its not fix the issue, Same exception occurred.